# VSCode Remote-SSH Cannot Connect

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use the Remote-SSH extension to edit files on a Linux server from my Windows 10 development machine. Normally, I log into the server using VNC and edit files locally OR I use WinSCP to pull the files to my development machine and copy them back over when done. The Remote-SSH extension seems to be the answer to this inefficiency.

I can SSH just fine using Putty or using Git Bash, but Remote-SSH fails to connect. There's some hints in the error message, but I'm not sure how to interpret them.

Here is my SSH config file (redacted) and the error I receive (redacted):

**Config:**

```
Host xxx.yy.gov
  HostName xxx.yy.gov
  User myusername
```

**Error Message:**

```
[08:44:36.981] remote-ssh@0.47.2
[08:44:36.981] win32 x64
[08:44:36.983] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+xxx.yy.gov", attempt 1
[08:44:36.983] SSH Resolver called for host: xxx.yy.gov
[08:44:36.983] Setting up SSH remote "xxx.yy.gov"
[08:44:37.030] Using commit id "[some-string-of-numbers]" and quality "stable" for server
[08:44:37.033] Testing ssh with ssh -V
[08:44:37.101] ssh exited with code: 0
[08:44:37.101] Got stderr from ssh: OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.4
[08:44:37.105] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 52772 xxx.yy.gov bash
[08:44:37.107] Install and start server if needed
[08:44:37.111] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[08:44:37.264] > 
[08:44:37.264] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[08:44:37.611] > myusername@xxx.yy.gov's password:
[08:44:37.612] Showing password prompt
[08:44:44.709] Got password response
[08:44:44.709] "install" wrote data to terminal: "**************"
[08:44:44.730] > 
> 
[08:44:45.102] > bash: bash: command not found
> 
[08:44:45.476] "install" terminal command done
[08:44:45.476] Install terminal quit with output: bash: bash: command not found
[08:44:45.476] Received install output: bash: bash: command not found
[08:44:45.477] Stopped parsing output early. Remaining text: bash: bash: command not found
[08:44:45.477] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[08:44:45.477] Resolver error: 
[08:44:45.480] TELEMETRY: {"eventName":"resolver","properties":{"outcome":"failure","reason":"UnparsableOutput",
"askedPw":"1","askedPassphrase":"0","asked2fa":"0","askedHostKey":"0","gotUnrecognizedPrompt":"0",
"remoteInConfigFile":"1"},"measures":{"resolveAttempts":1,"retries":1}}
[08:44:45.482] ------
```

[VSCode Remote-SSH error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTRqC.png)

Comment: I also have this exact problem, when connecting it tries to run bash command that ofcourse doesn't exist on Windows. Did you find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

There are there are three ways you can try. I know the problem is annoying.

1. Check your vscode is local window or remote window. Then, check
   remote-ssh setting. (Make sure Local Server Download is auto && Use
   local Server is marked.).
2. Remote SSH:Path . you can switch to local ssh or git/ssh
3. **Try to update or revert remote-ssh.(Version 0.50 can connect to server host stably, I found.** This one is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just select 'Linux' instead of 'Windows' though you are using Windows when you got the option to select Linux, Windows or Mac.
Since you are connecting to a server and not your own computer, the type of server you are connecting to is most likely Linux.